# Making a MySql query to execute when a java button is clicked

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to execute a MySql query when a `JButton` is pressed. How can I do it?

Here is the code I used for connection:

```
Connection con=null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?" 
                    + "autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "open");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from books3");
    while (rs.next()) {
         System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"   "+rs.getString(2));
    }
    System.out.println("Connection Established");
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering as you are a new user otherwise what you are asking is very trivial.

Refer these answers - [run function on JButton press](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583541/3850730) , [How to create on click event for buttons in swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21879526/3850730)  to know more about reaching to a piece of Java back end code at button press event in Swing. In summary, you need to use an `ActionListener` on your button to do that.

Next , you can call your method containing your code snippet from there.

Addition Advice - Your Java code is bad in terms of connection leaks. I would write code this way to close connections , statements & result sets automatically by moving them inside `try`.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
    try(Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?" + "autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","open");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from books3");
        ){
        while (rs.next()) {
             System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"   "+rs.getString(2));
        }
    System.out.println("Connection Established and Query Executed");
    }
```